# .Net Core Global Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

It's my first time using a `Filter` and it's not working.  This is a really simple example.  Nothing is added to the response header and the breakpoint is not hit in the filter class.  I want this to be a global filter. What am I missing or doing wrong?

**FILTER**:

```
public class TestFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var headerName = "OnResultExecuting";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(
            headerName, new string[] { "ResultExecutingSuccessfully" });
    }
}
```

**STARTUP.CS**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
    services.AddCors();

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new TestFilter());
    });
}
```

**CONTROLLER METHOD:**

```
[HttpGet("", Name = "search")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PagedResult<SearchViewModel>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
```

Comment: You really shouldn’t throw a `NotImplementedException` from the filter. That will interrupt everything and prevent you from getting any valid results. Also note that result filters will only execute when there’s a proper result from the MVC action. So you will have to verify that you are testing it with a properly working MVC action. – Do you get any error at all?

Comment: @poke...You're comment about NotImplementedException is valid, but it's just a test for now. I've added this code to a working application. No errors are being thrown

Comment: That's a `ResultFilter` you added. Did you make sure you're calling an action that returned a `IActionResult`?

Comment: @haim770...yes, but Task<IActionResult>.  Could that be it?  I need to make it async?

Comment: @BigDaddy If it's not `async` then `Task.Result` isn't being unwrapped hence it can be a problem since the framework might not consider it a valid `IActionResult`...

Comment: @haim770 That’s not correct. The pipeline will properly run asynchronous actions and await their resulting task. That does not affect filters.

Comment: @poke, Yes. It was only a guess and apparently a wrong one.

Comment: @haim770...I changed the filter to IAsyncActionFilter and no luck.  I've posting the method declaration

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. So maybe there is some additional configuration we are not aware of

Comment: @Alexander...well that's good and bad :)  What could I be missing?

Comment: @BigDaddy Who knows) Are you making cors request? And how do you test it, via javascript or postman?

Comment: @Alexander...Yes, it's making a cors request via javascript

Comment: Try share us the request network tab in the web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to let javascript read response headers while making cross-origin request you need to build `CORS` policy in `ASP.NET Core` application that [exposes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) certain headers to client

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ResultHeader", policy =>
    {
        policy
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithExposedHeaders("OnResultExecuting"); //headers to be exposed
    });
});
```

And you use it globally

```
app.UseCors("Default");
```

or for specific action/controller only

```
[HttpGet("", Name = "search")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PagedResult<SearchViewModel>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[EnableCors("ResultHeader")] //enabling cors requests
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
```

Comment: This is what I was missing (javascript client): .WithExposedHeaders("OnResultExecuting"); //headers to be exposed

Comment: Access-Control-Expose-Headers has my added header.  For a common header like Content-Disposition, does the client need to do anything to retrieve it?

Comment: @BigDaddy According to the article referenced in my answer only `Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type` headers are always available and you don't need to "expose" them, and I'd just test it with different browsers to see if certain header is available and should be exposed or not. Concerning breakpoints, I don't know. Apparently filter is executed and you can see the result so it should be something wrong with debugging but I cannot say what exactly.

Comment: The problem is I don't have controllers in this website.  It's a gateway api - acts as a reverse proxy.  So, the only hooks I got are in Configure and ConfigureServices.  I'm thinking custom middleware is the solution.